# Displaying Interlinear Text that is aligned with each other

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, repeater

I have two data sources. The first is from the Stephens Greek Text and the second is a literal translation in English. I need a method of aligning the English translation with the Greek Text. However, the alignment is based on small groups of Greek words that correspond to small groups of English words. However the group of either could be 1 word in length. And the groups many not be the same number of words in length.

This is an asp.net win forms application with an mssql backend database. I can do some alignment of an entire verse of each text, but that won't help as the English translation needs to be under each Greek word or phrase corresponding to it.

I am using Bootstrap and a repeater control to populate a paragraph tag. If each word in each text is assigned a word_group_id, is there a "manual" way to pull in the words by word_group and manually populate the repeater control, by setting limits by line how much it gets populated.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. Please [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve]

Comment: Post your code for further analysis.